# Using R to count number of observations by group and condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been using Excel but want to transition over to R but am getting overwhelmed. In excel I use the countifs function a lot to count the instantizes that meet multiple conditions. I have a large CSV with each row containing information about properties (State, pasture area, soy area, corn area, etc.) I want to produce a new table of the counts of properties by state with different conditions. Below is an example of the data I have:

| Prop_ID | State | Pasture | Soy | Corn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WI | 20 | 45 | 75 |
| 2 | MN | 10 | 80 | 122 |
| 3 | MN | 152 | 0 | 15 |
| 4 | IL | 0 | 10 | 99 |
| 5 | IL | 75 | 38 | 0 |
| 6 | WI | 30 | 45 | 0 |
| 7 | WI | 68 | 55 | 0 |

I'm looking to produce a new table like this:

| State | Cnt by state | Cnt >25 Pasture | Cnt >25 Soy | Cnt>25 Pasture AND Soy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WI | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| MN | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| IL | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Which is the count per state of properties that have >25 pasture, >25 soy, >25 pasture and soy etc. I'm trying to use dplyr but maybe there is another package that's better for this? So on a side note is there a good class or site that can help me learn the basics of reorganizing and pulling simple statistics out of large tables like I am trying to do here?

Comment: [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) is a good book to get started on reorganizing, analyzing data and is free online

Comment: `dat %>% group_by(State) %>% summarize(\`Cnt by state\`=n(), \`Cnt >25 Pasture\`=sum(Pasture>25), \`Cnt >25 Soy\`=sum(Soy>25), \`Cnt >25 Pasture AND Soy\` = sum(Pasture>25 & Soy>25))`

Comment: (I think that's the first time I've seen three identical answers in the same minute!)

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks for your reply! I have more more question if you don't mind. What would I add to this code if I wanted another column that, for example, was the sum of pasture but only for properties with >25 pasture, so the result for WI would be 98. I was playing around with the code and see if you removed the conditions is actually sums the values by each state but with the conditions added it returns the count.

Comment: I think `dat %>% group_by(State) %>% summarize(new_thing = sum(Pasture * Pasture >25))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarize(Cnt_by_state = n(),
            Cnt_gt25_Past = sum(Pasture > 25),
            Cnt_gt25_Soy = sum(Soy > 25),
            Cnt_gt25_Past_Soy = sum(Pasture > 25 & Soy >25))
```

Result is by default sorted by alphabetical group…

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  State Cnt_by_state Cnt_gt25_Past Cnt_gt25_Soy Cnt_gt25_Past_Soy
  <chr>        <int>         <int>        <int>             <int>
1 IL               2             1            1                 1
2 MN               2             1            1                 0
3 WI               3             2            3                 2
```